# How can I check if a boolean from a different model is true for a user of a team?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-views

I have the following model I want to use to add rights to users that are part of a team:

```
class Rights(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    team = models.ForeignKey(Teams, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    read = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    write = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    edit = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

Some Users need to be able to make new entries. Some are not allowed to have that possibility. So, if some user sends a request, how can I check if one or more of these boolean values are true or false for this specific user?

Comment: Can there be multiple `Rights` for the same `user`-`team` combo?

Comment: One user can be in multiple teams. A distinct user team combo exists once and has the attributes read, write, edit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can obtain the `Rights` object that point to *`myuser`* and *`myteam`*, and then inspect the `read`, `write` and/or `edit` fields:

```
right = Rights.objects.get(user=myuser, team=myteam)
right.read  # bool, True or False
right.write  # bool, True or False
right.edit  # bool, True or False
```

You can ensure that for each `user`/`team` combination, there is at most one record with:

```
from django.conf import settings

class Right(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(
        settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE
    )
    team = models.ForeignKey(Teams, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    read = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    write = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    edit = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    class Meta:
        constraints = [
            models.UniqueConstraint(fields=('user', 'team'), name='unique_per_user_team')
        ]
```

---

> **Note**: It is normally better to make use of the [**`settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#std:setting-AUTH_USER_MODEL) to refer to the user model, than to use the [**`User`** model [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/auth/#django.contrib.auth.models.User) directly. For more information you can see the [*referencing the `User` model* section of the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/customizing/#referencing-the-user-model).

---

> **Note**: normally a Django model is given a *singular* name, so `Right` instead of <s>`Rights`</s>.

Comment: tysm this is very helpful